# Renaming Global Variable Without Breaking Reference

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

Is there a way to rename a Variable or Variable Group without breaking the references it already have in Tibco Business Works 5.x. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible in tibco bw5 designer but keep in mind that tibco bw5 project is just set of text files. Find and replace in project files will work for global variables renaming.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAbragimov. Someone told me to do the same thing but kinda hesitant to do it manually and hoping there would be some form of rename facility in Tibco that would do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A way you could do this is by editing the complete source code that is in XML. After taking a proper backup. 
You could identify the variable or variable group XML tags to be renamed and rename them by using an advanced text editor with Regular expressions if is the case.

Once you rename everything you would have to open TIBCO Designer and go to the root location of the project and validate All. Validate the complete project.

A manual cleanup and re-built, testing would be required.

Avoiding changes in a massive scale is advised. Less Risk.